# User-facing numbers: implementing them efficient, "operational" and round-off safe?

Tags: java

I have something similar to a **spreadsheet column** in mind. A spreadsheet column has transparent data typing: text or any kinds of numbers.

But no matter how the typing is implemented internally, they allow **roundoff-safe** operations; eg adding up a column of hundreds of numbers with decimal points, and other arithmetic operations. And they do it efficiently too.

What way of handling numbers can make them:

1. transparent to the user
2. round-off safe
3. support efficient arithmetic, aggregation, sorting
4. handled by datastores and applications with Java primitive types?

---

I have in mind, using a 64b `long` datatype that is internally multiplied by 1000 to provide 3 decimal places. For example `123.456` is internally stored as `123456`, `` `1 `` is stored as `1000`. Reinventing floating point numbers seems clunky; I have to reinvent multiplication, for example.

---

**Miscellany:** I actually have in mind a document tagging system. A number tag is conceptually similar to a spreadsheet column that is used to store numbers.

I do want to know how spreadsheets handle it, and I would have titled the question as such.

I am using two datastores that uses Java primitive types. Point #4 wasnt hypothetical.

Comment: Have you considered using BigDecimal? (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html)

Comment: @aitchnyu: *"Reinventing floating point numbers seems clunky"*... What you described wouldn't be re-inventing floating point.  You described "fixed point" ; )  It's not that clunky: it's very common to store cents using integers, for example.  But Java has BigDecimal, why not simply use that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel uses double precision floats internally, then rounds the *display* portion in each cell according to the formatting options. It uses the double values for any calculations (unless the Precision as Displayed option is enabled - in which case it uses the rounded displayed value) and then rounds the result when displayed.

You could certainly use a long normalized to the max number of decimals you want to support - but then you're stuck with fixed-precision. That may or may not be acceptable. If you can use BigDecimal, that could work - but I don't think that qualifies as a Java primitive type.

Comment: _"long normalized to the max number of decimals"_ : There are a max number of decimals involved. So its acceptable. Is there an established way for this?

Comment: BTW, does it use the high precision as protection against roundoff errors?

Comment: @aitchnyu - Yes, the established way is just as you've specified - store the integer representation, with a fixed decimal point. Floats, decimals, etc. give you arbitrary precision - which makes implmentation harder (but more flexible).

Comment: Would the high precision of `double` guard against roundoff errors , like Excel seems (to me) to have assumed? That is what I meant by my previous comment. But your comment led me to a few resources (like SO questions) to start with, for example of people who wanted to store money values.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you really need to use primatives, BigDecimal should handle that for you.